# Issue in Shell in Xamarin.Forms Flow direction

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am facing issue in Shell Flow Direction. RighttoLeft is not working with the Shell. The icon appears on the right which is correct but the Layout of the Shell is opening from the Left. I want to open it from the right. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I just test the shell with latest Xamarin.Forms version 4.6.0.847.

In iOS, it works well with `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`:

[image]

In Android, the flyout comes from left as you mentioned in your question.

Here are some relevant issues in Github: [Shell FlowDirection follows Device FlowDirection in all cases.](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6342) and [Xamarin.Forms Shell Opener Issue for "RTL Language" when Tap at Hamburger](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6227)

You can also open an issue in Github about this problem to get more support.

Comment: The 2 links are the same.